# Define The constructor File(Uri)?

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

i made a wallpaper set application, on my device (Nexus 5) it works great but on Galaxy TAB, Fame or even on Optimus it gives java.lang.OutOfMemory error.
someone told me to implement **public Bitmap decodeAndResizeFile(File f)** but i get

**here is my MainActivity code**
    package app.technozed.cablewallpapershd;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ImageView display;
int toPhone;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    System.gc();
    toPhone = R.drawable.wal1;
    display = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WPdisplay);
    ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WPimg1);
    ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WPimg2);
    ImageView image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WPimg3);
    ImageView image4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WPimg4);
    ImageView image5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WPimg5);
    ImageView image6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WPimg6);
    ImageView image7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WPimg7);
    ImageView image8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WPimg8);
    ImageView image9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WPimg9);
    ImageView image10 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WPimg10);
    Button setWall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BsetWall);
    image1.setOnClickListener(this);
    image2.setOnClickListener(this);
    image3.setOnClickListener(this);
    image4.setOnClickListener(this);
    image5.setOnClickListener(this);
    image6.setOnClickListener(this);
    image7.setOnClickListener(this);
    image8.setOnClickListener(this);
    image9.setOnClickListener(this);
    image10.setOnClickListener(this);       setWall.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

here i implemented it:

public Bitmap decodeAndResizeFile(File f) {

```
    try {
        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                    || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.WPimg1:
         display.setImageResource(R.drawable.wal1);
         toPhone = R.drawable.wal1;
```

here i retrive it:

> File file=new File(Uri.parse(String.valueOf(toPhone)));

on the line above i get *The constructor File(Uri) is undefined* error

```
Bitmap bmpp = decodeAndResizeFile(file);
display.setImageBitmap(bmpp);

         break;
    case R.id.WPimg2:
         display.setImageResource(R.drawable.wal2);
         toPhone = R.drawable.wal2;
         break;
    case R.id.WPimg3:
         display.setImageResource(R.drawable.wal3);
         toPhone = R.drawable.wal3;
         break;
    case R.id.WPimg4:
         display.setImageResource(R.drawable.wal4);
         toPhone = R.drawable.wal4;
         break;
    case R.id.WPimg5:
         display.setImageResource(R.drawable.wal5);
         toPhone = R.drawable.wal5;
         break;
    case R.id.WPimg6:
         display.setImageResource(R.drawable.wal6);
         toPhone = R.drawable.wal6;
         break;
    case R.id.WPimg7:
         display.setImageResource(R.drawable.wal7);
         toPhone = R.drawable.wal7;
         break;
    case R.id.WPimg8:
         display.setImageResource(R.drawable.wal8);
         toPhone = R.drawable.wal8;
         break;
    case R.id.WPimg9:
         display.setImageResource(R.drawable.wal9);
         toPhone = R.drawable.wal9;
         break;
    case R.id.WPimg10:
         display.setImageResource(R.drawable.wal10);
         toPhone = R.drawable.wal10;
         break;
    case R.id.BsetWall:
         try{
               WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setResource(toPhone);
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wallpaper was set!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         } catch(IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No privileges!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
         break;
    }
    }
    }
```

how can i define it? what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The file class takes a java.net.URI in its constructor, you're trying to give it an android.net.Uri.

That's what's wrong as far as I can see.

The File class you're using:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Takes this URI class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html

You're passing this: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URI.html

Comment: i defined Uri like this:
  **Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    File file = new File(picturePath);// 
    Bitmap bmpp = decodeAndResizeFile(file);**

but `data.getData();` doesn't want to work saying: data cannot be resolved

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered this error so many times... Finally I came out with one common method to set the image view... Following is the code fragment...

```
public static void setImageView(ImageView imageView, String path) {
        Log.i("Atul Dravid", path);
        if (path.startsWith("Photo") || path.startsWith("null"))
            return;
        path = path.startsWith("/") ? path : path.substring(6);
        Bitmap picture = (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        picture = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(picture, 200, 200, false);
        picture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, stream);
        byte[] bitmapArray = stream.toByteArray();
        picture = (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapArray, 0, bitmapArray.length);
        //imageView.setImageURI(fileUri);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(picture);
        imageView.setContentDescription(path);


    }
```

You may want to modify above code for your requirement of resolution of the picture.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

Technically only difference is that I also added Scaling in my code... Try introducing that in your code fragment... I have not found any noticeable degradation in quality of the picture...

Comment: and how can i call it in my cases?
 `case R.id.WPimg4:
       display.setImageResource(R.drawable.wal4);
       toPhone = R.drawable.wal4;
       break;`

Comment: i want to scale it, but it should fit my phone screen, how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your compile error is because there is no constructor for the class 'File' that takes a Uri object as a parameter. To construct a File object using an Uri, you would do usually call getPath() on the URI to return its path as a String:

```
File file=new File(Uri.parse(String.valueOf(toPhone)).getPath());
```

However that will still not solve your problem because 'toPhone' is an integer representing the id of a resource in your project (in this case a drawable). You cannot generate a URI or file path from a resource id in that manner. However in this case, you can work directly with the resource id instead of a file anyway.

Change your decode method to accept a resource identifier (i.e. an integer):

```
public Bitmap decodeAndResizeFile(int resID) {
```

...and use the decodeResource method of BitmapFactory instead of decodeStream (using your Activity's context):

```
Bitmap bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resID, o);
```

Then you can call it with:

```
Bitmap bmpp = decodeAndResizeFile(toPhone);
```

Easiest way to get the context is to declare it as a variable in your Activity class:

```
private Context context;
```

...and set it in onCreate():

```
context = this;
```

You can then use it wherever you need to in your activity.

Comment: should i define it:
`Context context;

public myClass(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}`

Comment: Please see my edit above. The easiest way is to store a reference to your activity's context in onCreate.

Comment: the `} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         }
         return null;
     }` says
*Unreachable catch block for FileNotFoundException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body*
can i leave only `} catch (Exception e) {` ?

Comment: Yes. If you are no longer using a file, that exception can no longer occur. So you can remove the try/catch.

Comment: `case R.id.WPimg1:`
    `display.setImageResource(R.drawable.wal1);`
    `toPhone = R.drawable.wal1;`
    `File file=new` `File(Uri.parse(String.valueOf(toPhone)).getPath());`
    `Bitmap bmpp = decodeAndResizeFile(toPhone);`
    `break;`
mmmm.. i'm not able to use bmpp more then 1 time,
can i use it like this: **bmpp = decodeAndResizeFile(toPhone);** ?

Comment: Declare 'Bitmap bmpp;' once before the switch statement. Then you can use 'bmppp=decode..." as many times as you like. Remove the 'File file=new File...' statement as well since you don't need it and it won't work anyway...

Comment: all seems ok, but the app doesn't want to start, can you please take a look i created another question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410641/error-inflating-class-when-trying-to-decodestream)